# How can I keep track of file path name in recursive function?

Tags: c, linux, file

I currently have a function that will go through a directory and print every file in each directory.

```
void printdir(char *dir, int depth)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat statbuf;
    if ((dp = opendir(dir))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open director: %s\n", dir);
        return;
    }
    chdir(dir);
    while((entry = readdir(dp))!=NULL)
    {
        lstat(entry->d_name, &statbuf);
        if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
        {
            if(strcmp(".", entry ->d_name)==0 || strcmp("..", entry->d_name) ==0)
                continue;
            printf("directory %*s%s/\n", depth, "", entry->d_name);
            printdir(entry->d_name, depth+4, path);

        }
        else printf("file %*s/%s\n", depth, "",entry->d_name);
    }
    chdir("..");
    closedir(dp);
}
```

I need to keep track of the whole path name. I originally did this by having a malloc string

```
char *path = malloc(sizeof(char)*500);
```

and then I strcat the original filename (obtained from user) to path. I then made path a parameter, so any time I opened a new directory, I would add the name to path. The only problem with this, is that I don't know when to 'reset' path if that makes sense. So if I have directoryA with directoryB,C,D, when I leave in directory B, I need to reset path to "./directoryA" and then add directory C. Basically if anyone could look at the code I have and see if there's a way to edit it so I could keep track of the file name, that would be very helpful!
Thank you!

Comment: If you make the variables that stored the path local, you do not have to 'reset' it. Each recursive call will have it's own value. Returning from the function to the previous call will restore the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack is your friend, use it.
The example below uses the stack as means to keep reference of where you are.
the `dir` argument to `printdir` is now a copy.
Also - since you now have a full path, you no longer need to `chdir` anymore.
Finally, added `goto bail` instead of return to free the directory handle on error.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <alloca.h>
#include <limits.h>

void printdir(char *dir, int depth)
{
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *entry;
    struct stat statbuf;
    if ((dp = opendir(dir))==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open director: %s\n", dir);
        goto bail;
    }
    //chdir(dir);
    while((entry = readdir(dp))!=NULL)
    {            
        size_t dir_len = strlen(dir);
        size_t name_len = strlen(entry->d_name);
        char* child = (char*)alloca((dir_len + name_len + 1 /* our added '/' */ + 1 /* null termination */) * sizeof(char));
        if (child == NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"out of stack memory");
            goto bail;
        }
        // Copy the current dir + new directory to 'child'.
        // Could use strcpy and then strcat instead
        memcpy(child,dir,dir_len);
        child[dir_len] = '/';
        memcpy(child + dir_len + 1,entry->d_name,name_len);
        child[dir_len + 1 + name_len] = '\0';

        lstat(child, &statbuf);
        if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
        {
            if(strcmp(".", entry ->d_name)==0 || strcmp("..", entry->d_name) ==0)
                continue;
            printf("directory %*s%s/\n", depth, "", child);
            printdir(child, depth+4);
        }
        else printf("file %*s/%s\n", depth, "",child);
    }
    //chdir("..");

bail:
    if (dp){
        closedir(dp);
    }
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    char* path = ".";
    printdir(path,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @kiranBiradar There is no need to free anything, `alloca` allocates stack memory.  it is automatically freed when the stack rewinds, it is also very fast to allocate since stack memory it is already pre-allocated, all the system needs to do is to move the stack pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you do not have to use malloc (and remember to free, on return). You can use local array, or VLA (variable length arrays). Assuming 'fullpath' is the third argument to printdir, and assuming initial call will pass "" to fullpath.

> void printdir(char *dir, int depth, char *fullpath)

Then

```
        if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
        {
            if(strcmp(".", entry ->d_name)==0 || strcmp("..", entry->d_name) ==0)
                continue;

            char newpath[500] ;     // auto variable, OR
            char path[strlen(fullpath) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 10) ;    // VLA
            snprintf(newpath, sizeof(newpath), "%s/%s", fullpath, entry->d_name)) ;

            psrintf("directory %*s%s/\n", depth, "", entry->d_name);
            printdir(entry->d_name, depth+4, newpath);

        }
```

Comment: I tried this, it didn't work - am I supposed to be setting newpath to something? I'm just not sure I understand what this code does

Comment: The snprintf will set newpath value. Can you clarify what does not work ?

Comment: it just didn't print anything in front of the file names

Answer (score -1):

Since you are doing `DFS` you can simply do as below without adding new argument as said by @dash-o.

```
if(S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode))
{
    if(strcmp(".", entry ->d_name)==0 || strcmp("..", entry->d_name) ==0)
        continue;

    char newpath[500] ;     // auto variable, OR
    char path[strlen(dir) + strlen(entry->d_name) + 10) ;    // VLA
    snprintf(newpath, sizeof(newpath), "%s/%s", dir, entry->d_name)) ;

    psrintf("directory %*s%s/\n", depth, "", entry->d_name);
    printdir(newpath, depth+4);

}
```

Also remove, you don't need it anymore.

```
chdir(dir);
```

Comment: this doesn't make sense, where does fullpath come from then?